# To summarize difference from present row to the previous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Calculating the difference from present row to the previous, I have a simple data set and codes below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Month' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
'Rainfall': [112,118,132,129,121,135,148,148,136,119,104,118]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Rainfall = df["Rainfall"]

df['Changes'] = Rainfall.shift(-1) - Rainfall

df['Changes'] = df['Changes'].shift(1)
```

It shows the changes (as the left part of the picture). However I only care about if the change is positive, negative or zero (like the right part of the picture)

[image]

I tried to add an IF condition but it gives me error:

```
if df['Changes'] > 0:
    df['Changes'] = df['Changes'].shift(1)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What's the right way to achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {1:'Positive', -1:'Negative',0:'Zero'}
df['Changes'] = np.sign(df['Changes'].shift(1)).map(d).fillna('')

print (df)
    Month  Rainfall   Changes
0       1       112        
1       2       118  Positive
2       3       132  Positive
3       4       129  Negative
4       5       121  Negative
5       6       135  Positive
6       7       148  Positive
7       8       148      Zero
8       9       136  Negative
9      10       119  Negative
10     11       104  Negative
11     12       118  Positive
```

Another solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
s = df['Changes'].shift(1)
df['Changes'] = np.select([s < 0, s > 0, s == 0],
                          ['Negative','Positive','Zero'], 
                           default='')
```

EDIT:

```
df['Changes'] = df['Changes'].shift(1)
bins = np.arange(-100, 100, step=5)
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df['Changes'] = pd.cut(df['Changes'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
    Month  Rainfall Changes
0       1       112     NaN
1       2       118     0-5
2       3       132     0-5
3       4       129    -5-0
4       5       121    -5-0
5       6       135     0-5
6       7       148     0-5
7       8       148    -5-0
8       9       136    -5-0
9      10       119    -5-0
10     11       104    -5-0
11     12       118     0-5
```

Comment: thank you and glad to see you again, sir. hope you are well. would it be possible to have ranges for the categories, e.g. 1-5, 5-10 etc

Comment: I tried something like "d = {(1,5): '1-5', (-1, -5) : "-1 - -5" , 0:0}" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkK - What is maximal value and what minimal ? `-100, +100` and step is `5` ?

Comment: @MarkK - Then use `pd.cut`, but if use also negative values there are bins defined also with `0`, check `print (labels)` for ranges. So omit `0` is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

`if` condition doesn't work for a `pandas.Series`. Once you have created `Changes` by `df['Changes'] = (Rainfall.shift(-1) - Rainfall) / Rainfall`, use following to calculate just the positive or negative -

```
df['Changes'] = np.where(df['Changes'] >0, 'positive', 'negative')
df['Changes'] = df['Changes'].shift(1)
```